# Global Function block?

Tags: python, function

I am currently making a game in Python. Whenever you want help in the game, you just type **help** and you can read the help section.

The only problem is, I need to add a function block for each level.

```
def level_01():
    choice = raw_input('>>>: ')
    if choice=='help':
        level_01_help()


def level_012():
    choice = raw_input('>>>: ')
    if choice=='help':
        level_02_help()
```

So I was wondering if is possible to make a global function block for all the levels?
When you enter help, you get to help(), and then it automatically goes back to the function block you just came from.

I really hope you understand what I mean, and I would really appreciate all the help I could get.

Comment: By "function block," do you mean the first part (`choice = raw_input('>>>: ')` etc.) or the help functions for each level, i.e. `level_01_help`, `level_02_help`, etc.?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but you *always* "go back to the function block you just came from" after calling a function, you don't have to do anything special to make this happen. It'll happen by itself when you reach the end of your `help()` function.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually pass the help function as a paramater, meaning your code can become:

```
def get_choice(help_func):
    choice = raw_input('>>>: ')
    if choice == 'help':
        help_func()
    else:
        return choice

def level_01():
    choice = get_choice(level_01_help)

def level_02():
    choice = get_choice(level_02_help)
```

Ideally you should have a separate Module for all interface related tasks, so that the game and interface will be two seperate entities. This should make those 2911 lines a bit more legible, and if you decide to change Interfaces (from Command Line to Tkinter or Pygame for example) you will have a much much easier time of it. Just my 2¢

Comment: `get_choice` should be
def get_choice(help_func):
    while 1:
        choice = raw_input('>>>: ')
        if choice != 'help': return choice
        help_func()

Otherwise, it will return None after a help request, the levels will need to take charge of this situation, and very little would have been gained.

Comment: @MarioRossi I almost added something along those lines but decided he's probably already handling that in the help function itself as he doesn't include a while loop in his original code. +1 for noticing though :)

Answer (score 4):

A really nice way to handle this kind of problem is with the built in python help.  If you add [docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to  your function, they are stored in a special attribute of the function object called **doc**.  You can get to them in code like this:

```
def example():
    '''This is an example'''

print example.__doc__
>> This is an example

you can get to them in code the same way:
def levelOne():
   '''It is a dark and stormy night. You can look for shelter or call for help'''
   choice = raw_input('>>>: ')
   if choice=='help':
       return levelOne.__doc__
```

Doing it this way is a nice way of keeping the relationship between your code and content cleaner (although purists might object that it means you can't use pythons built-in help function for programmer-to-programmer documentation)

I think in the long run you will probably find that levels want to be classes, rather than functions - that way you can store state (did somebody find the key in level 1? is the monster in level 2 alive) and do maximum code reuse.  A rough outline would be like this:

```
class Level(object):
    HELP = 'I am a generic level'

    def __init__(self, name, **exits):
       self.Name = name
       self.Exits = exits # this is a dictionary (the two stars) 
                          # so you can have named objects pointing to other levels

    def prompt(self):
       choice = raw_input(self.Name + ": ")
       if choice == 'help':
           self.help()
       # do other stuff here, returning to self.prompt() as long as you're in this level

       return None # maybe return the name or class of the next level when Level is over

    def help(self):
       print self.HELP

  # you can create levels that have custom content by overriding the HELP and prompt() methods:

  class LevelOne (Level):
     HELP = '''You are in a dark room, with one door to the north. 
        You can go north or search'''

     def prompt(self):
       choice = raw_input(self.Name + ": ")
       if choice == 'help':
           self.help() # this is free - it's defined in Level
       if choice == 'go north':
           return self.Exits['north']
```

Comment: Don't you mean `print self.__doc__` instead of `print self.HELP`; or in LevelOne `HELP = '''You are in a dark room...'''` instead of the doc string?  Otherwise you always get Level.HELP...

Comment: In derived classes you would override the class level HELP; self.HELP will always be the HELP for the current class - that way you could, for example, have multiple rooms with the same description but different options based on previous state or something

Comment: Okay, then in LevelOne, shouldn't that doc string be assigned to the HELP property?

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to store the level you are on as a variable and have the help function handle all of the help stuff.

Example:

```
def help(level):
    # do whatever helpful stuff goes here
    print "here is the help for level", level

def level(currentLevel):
    choice = raw_input('>>>: ')
    if choice=='help':
        help(currentLevel)
    if ...: # level was beaten
        level(currentLevel + 1) # move on to the next one
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's always possible to generalize.  But with the little information you provide (and assuming "help" is the only common functionality), the original code is extremely straightforward.  I wouldn't sacrifice this property only to save 1 line of code per level.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I don't want reveal too much of the game I am making. Of course, I could provide some more information.

I have currently 2911 lines of code, and that's just a small part of level 1. This will absolutely help me out.